# Does this infinite series converge?

Tags: calculus

I need help proving that this infinite sequence converges:

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2})^n$

I am trying to do the ratio test and have gotten to this point:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2})^n+1}{(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2})^n})$

I'm stuck on what to do next

Comment: This is simply a geometric series.

Comment: Write $a=1/(1+\sqrt{2})$; then the ratio test asks you to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n}$ which is obviously $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have complicated terms, use algebra. Set
$$
a=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}
$$
Then the series is
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a^n
$$
The ratio test asks you to compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n}
$$
and this should be easy enough, isn't it?

Now, can you prove that the limit is $<1$, so the ratio test guarantees convergence?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** it's a geometric series. You can even calculate the sum, leave alone check convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the ratio test let $x=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$, then we get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x^{n+1}/x^{n} = x = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$

You could also note that $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} < 1$ and it's a geometric series, therefore it converges.